# how to finish the inbuilt WiFi setting screen when it goes pause state

Tags: android, android-intent, preferences, android-wifi

In my app i am calling inbuilt WiFi setting form Preference.xml file.

I am using this code to call the in built WiFi setting

```
<Preference
        android:key="wi5"
        android:summary="click this for wi5 setting"
        <intent android:action="android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS" />
    </Preference>
```

when i am in WiFi setting and the WiFi setting go to pause state. i want to close the setting screen. How to achieve this

Comment: You are not going to achieve this unless you have control over the Settings Activity (which you don't).

Comment: Is there any way to get control over the setting activity?